# cannot start React project with `npm start`: events.js:292 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

React version:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
```

npm version: `6.14.4`
yarn version: `1.22.0`
node version: `12.18.1` or `13.14.0`

### Steps To Reproduce

1. `git clone https://github.com/1846689910/type-18-hek.git`
2. cd in the project directory and run `yarn` or `npm i`
3. `yarn start` or `npm start`

- usually try 2 to 3 times for `yarn start`, the issue will happen

Link to code example: https://github.com/1846689910/type-18-hek

### The current behavior

After run `yarn start`

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

### The expected behavior

expect the project start normally, like `yarn run express`

Comment: its working for me boss

Comment: really? I cannot circle around this issue. I tried on Mac and Windows, no one is working. I actually don't know what cause this issue

Comment: oh im on linux, that may matter

Comment: im assuming it happens after the build step?

Comment: @aash Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Ancinek not yet. Still trapped by this. I found some similar issues related to event.js error, but those are not helpful

Comment: @here I think I figured out a solution, which are not 100% guaranteed will solve the issue when npm start every time, but it works most time. It may be issue with inotify watcher limit. Please check https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers. 
```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```
if `illegal option -- p`, maybe try `-e`

Comment: I had no idea how to solve this. Restarting my mac helped :|

Answer (score 0):

@here I think I figured out a solution, which are not 100% guaranteed will solve the issue when npm start every time, but it works most time. It may be issue with inotify watcher limit. Please check https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers.

```sh
$echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

if `illegal option -- p`, maybe try `sudo sysctl -e`

Answer (score -1):

> create-react-app my-app --scripts-version @nomoreanalog/react-scripts-eslintless
> create-react-app app1
> copy the node-modules nd package.json from my-app to app1
> cd app1
> npm start